# Locking table in mysql

Tags: mysql

Should one has to use lock manually in MySQL? or is it handled by the engine automatically?

Not in many PHP books, they have mentioned about locking tables.

Comment: you need to lock manually if you need the lock to persist across multiple queries.

Comment: Why would you want to lock a table?

Comment: @Barmar if i have a query like, $q=msyql_query("INSERT INTO students VALUES('', 'Richart')"); $last_insert_id = mysql_insert_id(); $q=mysql_query("INSERT INTO address VALUES('3','lake city', $last_insert_id));  In this scenario is lock needed?

Comment: No, you don't need a lock for that. `mysql_insert_id()` returns the last ID inserted on that specific connection. So other users inserting in the table at the same time will not interfere with it.

Comment: @Barmar - You do not need to lock tables. Best to avoid that. Have you heard of row/page locking and transactions (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/internal-locking.html). By adopting these methods you get better concurrency.